# how to invisible a Layout control in android

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

i'm using following code to set "visibility=gone" for a linear layout

```
      //onCreate method
      //setcontentview
        . . . . 
      LinearLayout rlayout1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.readerBottomLayout);
       rlayout1.setVisibility(2);
```

But the controls are still visible when activity runs.why? any idea?

Comment: You should post other code elements. These 2 lines should hide the control, I guess you've put them in the wrong place.

Comment: Firstly I would strongly suggest using the type rather than magic number, e.g. `setVisibility(View.GONE);`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

set rlayout1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)

Answer (score 10):

Yes, view.GONE and view.INVISIBLE will work. The reason it didn't work before is because two (2) is the incorrect integer value.

The correct values for set.Visibility are:

```
0 = visible
4 = invisible 
8 = gone
```

Answer (score 4):

you can also do something like this:

```
Get Parent layout object through its id
Get layout which you want to remove/hide through its id

parentlayout.remove(childlayout);
```